# Does the sequence converge? To what?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let α and β be positive real numbers and deﬁne a sequence by setting

$s_1 = \alpha, s_2 = \beta$ and $s_{n+2} = \frac12(s_n+s_{n+1})\forall n\in \Bbb \ge1$

Show that the subsequences $\{s_{2n}\}$ and $\{s_{2n-1}\}$ are monotonic and convergent. Does
the sequence $\{s_n\}$ converge? To what?

Comment: I have edited the question to improve the $\rm \TeX$ formatting. Can you check and tell if this is what you intended?

Comment: Yes this is what I intended. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are lost with this problem, try solving it first for $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1$.

The sequence goes $0,1,1/2,1/2+1/4,1/2+1/4-1/8=1/2+1/8,1/2+1/8+1/16,...$

The even terms are the partial sums of $1/2+1/8+1/32+...+1/2^{2k+1}+...$

We get as sum $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^2}}$.

Since the recurrence equation is linear we can scale and translate this solution to begin with $\alpha$  and $\beta$. We just need to multiply by $\beta-\alpha$ and add $\alpha$.